# Replace a character in file using c

Tags: c

I am trying to replace the character/string in a file with a character/string Request to provide solution/guidance

code snipet is below,

```
char stringtofind[4] = "]}";

fgets(get_line, sizeof(get_line), fileptr);
if (strstr(get_line,stringtofind) != NULL)
{
/* Help Required to replace the string "]}" with "," */
}
```

Comment: You can't replace two characters with one without rebuilding the whole string (well, at least the part that is coming after this substring).

Comment: Best is to read from one file, write to a 2nd file, then close and rename if successful.

Comment: In general, you will create a new file and place the edited text into the new file.  If the source and target text are not the same length (if you're not replacing N characters with N characters), then anything else is excruciating — it can be done, but don't try.  Even when the strings are the same length, creating a new file is simpler (by quite a margin).  When the new file is complete, you can arrange to rename the new file to the old name.

Comment: if you are trying to change the whole file, it would be easy, else the easiest way ( the only one i know) if you want to change a string within the file, is to create a new file fileToWriteIn, and open it in w mode, and you open the original file in r, you will iterate through the last one, and copy it to  fileToWriteIn, when you reach the string you pass it in the original file, and write the new string in fileToWriteIn, after that you would continue the copying process, when you reach EOF, you may delete the original file and rename fileToWriteIn

Comment: If you are just replacing occurrences of `]}` with a single character, you do not want to use `fgets`.  What happens when one `fgets` reads `]` as its final character, and the next reads the `}`? You do not want to add the complexity required to handle those overlaps for this simple case.  Use a simple state machine and read the data with `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *dupstringreplace(const char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace)
{
    char *newhaystack = NULL;
    const char *wrk = haystack;
    char *newwrk;
    ssize_t occurences = 0;
    size_t needleLen = strlen(needle);
    size_t replaceLen = strlen(replace);

    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        occurences++;
        wrk += needleLen;
    }
    newhaystack = malloc(strlen(haystack) + occurences * ((ssize_t)replaceLen - (ssize_t)needleLen) + 1);
    wrk = haystack;
    newwrk = newhaystack;
    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        memcpy(newwrk, haystack, wrk - haystack);
        newwrk += wrk - haystack;
        memcpy(newwrk, replace, replaceLen);
        newwrk += replaceLen;
        wrk += needleLen;
        haystack = wrk;
    }
    strcpy(newwrk, haystack);
    return newhaystack;
}


int main(void)
{
    FILE *fi = fopen("a.txt", "r+");
    long size;
    char *content, *replaced;

    fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fi); 
    fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET);


    content = malloc(size);
    if(content)
    {
        fread(content, 1, size, fi);
        replaced = dupstringreplace(content, "{[", ",");
        if(replaced)
        {
            fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(replaced, 1, size, fi);
        }
    }
    if(fi) fclose(fi);
    free(replaced);
    free(content);
}
```

Add some file error checks